# Is it possible to fake a session in PHP by setting cookies on client side using JS?

Tags: javascript, php, session, cookies

Supposedly, I am not using HttpOnly cookies for my session on a PHP web app. If a visitor is on a page that uses PHP sessions, they can see the session cookies. In addition to viewing, they can also delete or edit it.

The next case involves the user being on a page (say, normal page) on my web app that doesn't uses sessions and the normal page contains a link to a page which uses sessions (session page), having, `session_start()`. On the normal page, if a cookie is set (say using the console) with the same name as the one I use for session page, and the click is made on the link to the session page, what happens when I do `session_start()` on the session page?

Does it create a new session, or tries and map to a session with the value in the cookie being sent from the normal page?

If it maps, to an existing session value, then the session is said to be hijacked. What happens in the case when it doesn't map? Does it create a session cookie with a new value?

Even if I use HttpOnly for my sessions, it is sure that the session cookie cannot be read or manipulated using JS on the client side. But on the server, does the server read the same (HttpOnly) on the session cookie being sent to the server by the client and invalidates the session, in case it wasn't HttpOnly? Or does it try to map the value to existing sessions on the server?

Hope I was able to make it clear.

Comment: I am not sure what your question really is. But the HttpOnly flag does not matter for the server. The flag is for the client relevant. If it is set, then the browser doesn't let javascript have access to the cookie. The server does not know which cookies have HttpOnly flags and it does not matter.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois What did you not understand? Maybe, I can clarify.

Comment: If you set the right cookie value, yes you can steal a session.

Comment: And what if I set the wrong cookie value, that doesn't map to an actual session? Will `session_start()` write a new value to the session cookie or try to read session with a wrong value, meaning none of the set session variables would actually exist?

Comment: Then PHP will start a new session.

Comment: Guessing the sessionID isn't going to happen. I don't know the exact length of it but the probability of it happening is so unlikely. You would have better luck brute forcing the password.

Comment: goes back to the whole never trust session/cookie data really, so treat it just like a `GET` paramteter

Answer (score 2):

Sessions work in PHP like this.

When the user first visits the site and the PHP has `session_start()` it checks if the user is sending a cookie with a session ID. If they aren't then it creates one and sends it so the user stores it in a cookie. Then when the user visits another page `session_start()` can check if they already have a cookie and this time they do. Session cookies (stored on a user pc) are cleared when the browser is closed.

`session_start()` isn't creating a new session every time it is called. What it is doing is pulling in information about that session so it can be used further down in the code. When the user sends the session ID from their cookie, `session_start()` then pulls in the information stored about this session from the web server so then you can do things such as if you stored adminloggedin as true or false in their session. If the user didn't send a session ID then it doesn't pull any information from the server and just creates an ID and sends this back to the user to store in a cookie.

You don't need to use `session_start()` on every page however if you needed to check something from a users session such as if they are logged in then you need to call it in order to get the data about their session.

All information about a session is stored server side. For example, if I said the user was logged in and stored this in the session then this can be checked to allow access to admin pages. The user cannot fake this as all they are sending is the session ID and all the data about the session is stored server-side. They are not storing a cookie with information about the session, all they store is the ID for the session which is sent across.

Comment: Sessions can't be faked, but sessions can be hijacked.

Comment: And what do you say, when I want to use the hijacked session to represent the victim. How would you do that, provided the app doesn't allow session values to be passed through GET parameters. @Hallur?

Comment: I'm not sure i'm fully understanding what you're asking. You would never send a session value using GET.

Comment: I know it's possible but it shouldn't be used expect in a few circumstances. For almost any project it would be bad practice as you are making the chance of session hijacking much more likely as a user could share the URL without realising what the parameters mean. You would need lots of extra server-side checks to prevent session hijacking through using GET parameters for the session.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14093/why-is-passing-the-session-id-as-url-parameter-insecure

Comment: @M.V. Passing the SessionID by URL is bad practices and should be turned off, as you're making it easy for someone to hijack a session.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois, 
Please read a bit more carefully. You are talking out of the context on what I meant as a question to Hallur. It wasn't a statement. A question with a condition.

Comment: @M.V. What are you still wanting to know? Your question was fairly broad. Is there an aspect that you still want explaining?

Comment: @Ben Please read the comment carefully made as a reply to Hallur. It is a question. I'm not saying I am using it. Please don't speak out of the context. This makes the entire topic deviate to something else, which I don't think would be beneficial as far as this topic is concerned. Thank you.

Comment: @M.V. I don't understand the question. You're asking what can be done against session hijacking? There are lots of questions already answered on stackexchange about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233406/preventing-session-hijacking

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22880/what-is-the-best-way-to-prevent-session-hijacking

Comment: @Ben It is all in the question as far as I think. I don't think it is as broad, as one cannot think on. I would like an explanation on all aspects. I'm not clear on any of the ones here right now.

Comment: @M.V. If a cookie is set to replace the one already stored about the sessionID and then the server receives it and cannot find one then it will create a new session. You're next part of the question is asking about httponly. This is only seen by the browser. The web server will never know about this tag. If you stored a cookie as httponly then it is down to the browser to implement this properly.