# How can i change the value of default PHPSESSIP cookie value after login of the website?

Tags: php, cookies

> When i load my website then PHPSESSID is automatically set with value
>   after login in the website the value is remain same
>
> I want after login PHPSESSID will be change when user login in the
>   website so that session hacking is not possible

```
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max_age=0');
header('Expires: 0');
session_start();
```

Comment: if you change the session id, then the session that the user have will be invalid and the user will be logged out

Comment: Also, if an attacker can get the session id before you're logged in, then they can also, probably, get the new one after. So it's not that good of a protection, given the effort required to change the id (you need to collaborate with the front end, i.e. the cookie, and backend to change it)

Comment: is there any way to cookie not shown on client desktop?

Comment: No not really. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233406/preventing-session-hijacking

Comment: PHPSESSID is not set automatically, you set it. So simply don't set it for unauthenticated users

Comment: I didn't set in my code